# Swapping out background images for background gifs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I currently have four li's that all contain images inside them with the gifs also in that li but have a "display: none;" inline on them. And when you would hover over the li's, their images would swap with a realated gif, as seen here in this jQuery that I wrote:

```
jQuery(".swap").mouseenter(function () {
    var me = jQuery(this);
    me.attr('src', me.attr('src').replace('.jpg', '.gif'));
});
jQuery(".swap").mouseleave(function () {
    var me = jQuery(this);
    me.attr('src', me.attr('src').replace('.gif', '.jpg'));
});
```

And here is my html:

```
<li>
    <img class="swap" src="image-box.jpg" />
    <img class="swap" src="image-box.gif" />
</li>
<li>
    <img class="swap" src="image-box2.jpg" />
    <img class="swap" src="image-box2.gif" />
</li>
```

I noticed however that these gifs are currently still being loaded into my site on mobile even after hiding the elements and their containers. So I decided to make the images background images of a div inside the li (since links need to wrapped around the image itself) and now it's laid out like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
       <div class="swap" id="imageOne"></div>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
       <div class="swap" id="imageTwo"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

And the jQuery I wrote to swap out the images for the gifs is as follows:

```
jQuery("#imageOne").mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(image-box.gif)');
    });
jQuery("#ImageOne").mouseleave(function () {
        jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(image-box.jpg)');
    });

jQuery("#imageTwo").mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(image-box2.gif)');
    });
jQuery("#ImageTwo").mouseleave(function () {
        jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(image-box2.jpg)');
    });
```

So my question is how can I simplify this new script I wrote to make it more concise. On the actual site there are 4 li's so this jQuery looks huge and very messy. I know there must be a better way of swapping this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only difference between jpeg and gif filenames are the file extension (ie the file names are the same), you can still reuse your original script to replace the image's reference:

```
jQuery(".swap").mouseenter(function () {
    var me = jQuery(this);
    me.css('background-image', me.css('background-image').replace('.jpg', '.gif'));
});
jQuery(".swap").mouseleave(function () {
    var me = jQuery(this);
    me.css('background-image', me.css('background-image').replace('.gif', '.jpg'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="swap" style="background-image:url('image/image-1.jpg');"></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="swap" style="background-image:url('image/image-2.jpg');"></div>
</li>
```

You can prime your gifs on document ready so that they're already in the cache when you want to do the swap:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
    jQuery('.swap').each(function(){
    //create hidden image
    var $img = jQuery('<img>').css({
      'visibility':'hidden',
      'position':'absolute',
      'z-index:-1'
    });
    //create trigger once the image is loaded
    $img.on('load', function(){
      jQuery(this).remove();
    });
    //add to DOM
    jQuery('body').append($img);
    //set image source to call server for image
    $img.attr('src', jQuery(this).css('background-image').slice(4, -1).replace('.jpg', '.gif'))
  });
});
```

I have not tested this, but I'm assuming the same swaping logic should still be relevant.

Comment: How would the html have to be set up? Wouldn't the gif still need to be loaded somewhere on the page?

Comment: The .jpgs could be defined inline (assuming they're being generated by a script) to reduce maintenance overhead over having to define specific styling rules per instance in stylesheet. You can also have a quick javascript that will prime each animated gif into the cache on page ready.

Comment: So that's properly swapping them now, but I just need a way to stop them when you mouse out and then restart them when you mouse back in again